# Using Spring Security to Validate User Credentials

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have an application that uses Spring Security LDAP for User authentication.
What I'm trying to do is build a feature that requires the User to provide their password again for validation of credentials before performing an important process.

The user is already signed in, so I wouldn't want to kick the user out by killing their current session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate service and controller to make a simple LDAP auth and lookup.
The service would login with the Spring config settings, then apply the username and supplied password and validate CN result.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it could be a tricky requirement to fill. I have one somewhat outside the box solution that could meet the requirement:

1. Create a sister Grails application that uses the same Grails/Spring Security/LDAP structure as your primary app.
2. Expose a /verifyLdapCredentials Service in the sister application to accept the user's LDAP credentials
3. Authenticate against LDAP
4. Sends a success/failure response back to the primary application
5. Unauthenticate from the sister application immediately to prepare for the next request